Integrating CCAvenue Payment Gateway API with React Native
I'm currently working on integrating the CCAvenue payment gateway API with my React Native in 2024 application to facilitate payments within the app.
I've read the answers provided, but I'm still unsure how to send a request from my mobile app to CCAvenue to fetch available payment options. The explanations I've found haven't been helpful for my situation.
